# What does a reference letter for a postdoc/tenure-track position in math look like?

Tags: postdocs, recommendation-letter, job-search

I find myself in the unenviable position of having to draft the body of my own reference letter. I trust the recommender in question to actually treat it as a draft, and I know that they think highly of me as a researcher, but I'm totally stumped. I'm currently a postdoc and for this reason none of my mentors have been willing to share a sample letter with me. I also cannot find one online after trying for several hours.

So can anyone help by providing a *specific outline* of what such letters usually contain? Is it really almost entirely about research as suggested by my mentors and [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/122009/75018)? This is for postdoc fellowships and tenure-track positions in research-oriented universities, in math.

Comment: Writing your own recommendation letter? Sounds fishy.

Comment: I am aware, and I'm sure it has something to do with this person being outside of the US. But they did make it very clear that it was a *draft* that they would change. Anyways, my mentors recommended I go through with it, and now I have to.

Comment: [Here’s an example](https://www.vox.com/2015/6/6/8738229/john-nash-recommendation-letter).

Comment: Joking aside, based on this question your writing skills seem quite good enough to come up with something reasonable on your own. The premise that a recommendation letter has some sort of rigid structure that must be confirmed too or the letter will look fake is simply not correct. And as you said, your letter will be merely a draft and the official letter writer will make sure to edit out any obvious faux pas that you make, in the unlikely event that you will write something that clearly doesn’t belong in such a letter.

Comment: Haha, ah yes, my mistake - I saw the John Nash letter a couple of years ago. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Oops, I meant “conformed to”, not “confirmed too”. Must be an autocorrect.

Comment: @cgb5436 Ironically, "fishy" might be more applicable than one might think here (well not necessarily here but still): in Russian, the initial draft often provided by the side "requesting" the thing is called a fish. It happens all the time with recommendation letters, contracts and whatnot. Moreover, they're typically not confidential but profs have little issue trashing students nonetheless :-) The culture of references differs by country a lot.